# Examine two columns and delete lowest number of the id of column named contentid

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data comes from:

```
SELECT 
    CONTENTID, t1.TITLE, t1.PAGEID, COUNT, SPACENAME, CREATIONDATE, LASTMODDATE, VERSION 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         SPACEID, TITLE, PAGEID, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
     FROM 
         CONTENT
     WHERE 
         CONTENTTYPE = 'ATTACHMENT'
     GROUP BY 
         TITLE, PAGEID, SPACEID
     HAVING 
         COUNT(TITLE) > 1 AND COUNT(PAGEID) > 1) t1
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         CONTENTID, CREATIONDATE, LASTMODDATE, VERSION, TITLE, PAGEID 
     FROM 
         CONTENT 
     WHERE 
         VERSION = 1) t4 ON t4.PAGEID = t1.PAGEID
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         SPACEID, SPACENAME 
     FROM 
         SPACES) t2 ON t1.SPACEID = t2.SPACEID 
ORDER BY 
    t1.PAGEID,t1.TITLE, CREATIONDATE, LASTMODDATE
```

Output (removed some of the columns because it is just the first two needed to make the decision on what to remove and it is easier to display here):

```
CONTENTID   TITLE
--------------------------------------------
26902677    Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx
46170401    Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx
157909073   Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx
157909072   Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx
355860497   Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx
535953771   Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx
540117589   Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx
554729950   Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx
1246646     Induction Plan Template.docx
472350756   Induction Plan Template.docx
535953845   Induction Plan Template.docx
544508546   Induction Plan Template.docx
544508547   Induction Plan Template.docx
```

I need to delete all but the highest contentid for each title.  There are actually about 66k of rows of this type of fix

The end result for the output above:

```
554729950   Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx
544508547   Induction Plan Template.docx
```

Comment: `Select Max(ContentID), Title ... Group by Title` ?

Comment: `DELETE` from your table(s), or ignore in your query results?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it is simply:

```
DELETE FROM CONTENT WHERE CONTENTID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(CONTENTID) FROM CONTENT GROUP BY TITLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate a number for every row of data, and `PARTITION` it by the TITLE column descending. This would give you a number of 1 for the highest CONTENTID for every TITLE. You can then delete everything that does not have a row number of 1.

Here's an example.

```
-- create a temp table to store the test data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test_data') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #test_data 
CREATE TABLE #test_data (
    content_id INT NOT NULL, 
    title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

-- add the test data
INSERT INTO #test_data
SELECT 26902677    , 'Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx'
UNION SELECT 46170401    , 'Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx'
UNION SELECT 157909073  , 'Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx'
UNION SELECT 157909072  , 'Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx'
UNION SELECT 355860497  , 'Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx'
UNION SELECT 535953771  , 'Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx'
UNION SELECT 540117589  , 'Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx'
UNION SELECT 554729950  , 'Time Logging Guidelines V5.docx'
UNION SELECT 1246646      , 'Induction Plan Template.docx'
UNION SELECT 472350756  , 'Induction Plan Template.docx'
UNION SELECT 535953845  , 'Induction Plan Template.docx'
UNION SELECT 544508546  , 'Induction Plan Template.docx'
UNION SELECT 544508547  , 'Induction Plan Template.docx';

-- generate an row number for each row of the data
WITH ordered AS (
    SELECT
        content_id, 
        title,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY title ORDER BY content_id DESC) AS row_num
    FROM 
        #test_data
        )

-- delete all the rows that are not equal to 1
DELETE d
FROM #test_data d
INNER JOIN ordered o ON d.content_id = o.content_id AND o.row_num > 1

-- check the results
SELECT * FROM #test_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want.  I'm not sure what the purpose of the joins.  If all you want is to delete all records expect the higest `CONTENTID`, you can try this

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TITLE ORDER BY CONTENTID DESC) AS rn
    FROM Content
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: It is very specific data in the table, not just looking for highest contentid and deleting eveything else.  If you image, there are rows with version not equal to 1 where the title is the same and the pageid is the same.  That is what the original query is doing with drawing out just rows that have version = 1, pageid and title are the same for that pageid.